# Spark, ignore some input files

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have my data on hdfs, the folder structure is something like,

- hdfs://ns1/abc/20200101/00/00/
- hdfs://ns1/abc/20200101/00/01/
- hdfs://ns1/abc/20200101/00/02/
- ......

Basically, we create folder every minute and put hundreds of files in the folder.

We have a spark (2.3) application (written in java) which processes data on a daily basis, so the input path we used is like hdfs://ns1/abc/20200101, simple and straight, but sometime, a few files are corrupt or zero size, this causes the whole spark job failed.

So is there a simpe way to just ingore any bad file? have tried **--conf spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true**, but doesnt help at all.

Or can we have some 'file pattern' on command-line when submitting spark job, since those bad files are usually using different file extension.

Or, since I'm using JavaSparkContext#newAPIHadoopFile(path, ...) to read data from hdfs, any trick I can do with JavaSparkContext#newAPIHadoopFile(path, ...), so that it will ignore bad file?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, since bad files have a different extension, why don't you just read with `hdfs://ns1/abc/20200101/*/*/filepattern*.goodextension`?

Comment: @ernest_k, problem is none of those good files have extension...